# Encountering "TransportError" with socket.io-client in React Native Production Mode

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, socket.io, socket.io-client

Description:

I'm facing an issue while using socket.io-client in React Native's production mode. The error {"type": "TransportError", "description":0} occurs when attempting to establish a connection. Interestingly, this problem doesn't manifest in development mode.

Error Details:

Error Type: TransportError
Description: 0
Steps Tried:

Ran the application in production mode under different configurations.
Attempted installation of different versions of socket.io-client.
Current Situation:

Even after trying various versions of socket.io-client, the issue persists, preventing successful connections in production mode.

Versions Used:

react-native: 0.72.6
socket.io-client: 3.1.3
Request for Help:

If anyone has encountered and resolved a similar issue or has suggestions to address this problem in production mode, I'd greatly appreciate your guidance. Any insights or potential solutions would be incredibly valuable.

Thank you for your help in advance!

I tried running the application with various versions of socket.io-client to establish a successful connection in production mode. However, despite changing versions, the issue persisted. I expected the different versions to resolve the connection problem, but unfortunately, it didn't resolve the TransportError.